# Change the text of a label after clicking a button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I do not get why the text of my label is not updating after clicking a button. If I want to show the output on the console, there is no problem.

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets
from UI.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.calc_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_calc_btn_click)

    def on_calc_btn_click(self):
        weight = int(self.ui.weight_textbox.text())
        height = int(self.ui.height_textbox.text())
        bmi = weight/height**2

        print(str(bmi)) # -> works
        self.ui.bmi_label.setText(str(bmi)) # -> label does not update


window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: share `Ui_MainWindow` class

Comment: The UI_MainWindow class is auto generated by QT. There are only set the default styles

Comment: Well then share it, since according to the logic you show there should be no problems

Comment: It works correctly in PyQt5, the text of the shortcut is updated after clicking the button.

Comment: @Baflora As S.Nick points out your code works correctly, do you have any error messages? What qtpy backend are you using? What is your OS? If you are using qtpy as PyQt5 backend then what version of PyQt5 do you have?

Comment: I am using MacOS and PyQt5 on the latest version (5.13.0)

Comment: And not even the window title is changed after set it up with QT creator...i reinstalled qt and all packages at PyCharm..

Answer (score 0):

```
#Try This

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
class Ui_CalcBMI(object):
    def setupUi(self, CalcBMI):
        CalcBMI.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("CalcBMI"))
        CalcBMI.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(CalcBMI)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 220, 111, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.On_Update_Clicked)
        #add textbox here to get height and weight
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(CalcBMI)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 70, 131, 101))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.retranslateUi(CalcBMI)
    def On_Update_Clicked(self):
        #Get values from textbox and calculate bmi here
        bmi="23.5"
        self.label.setText(bmi)
    def retranslateUi(self, CalcBMI):
        CalcBMI.setWindowTitle(_translate("CalcBMI", "CalcBMI", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("CalcBMI", "Calculate now", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("CalcBMI", "inProgess", None))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_X11InitThreads)
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    CalcBMI = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_CalcBMI()
    ui.setupUi(CalcBMI)
    CalcBMI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```